# Happy number - Leetcode challenge

Tags: c

I've written the code for the * Happy Number *

Whats' a happy number? Example :

Input: 19

Output: true

Explanation:

1^2 + 9^2 = 82

8^2 + 2^2 = 68

6^2 + 8^2 = 100

1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1  . Those numbers for which this process ends in **1** are happy numbers.

My code:

```
bool isHappy(int n){
        int sum=0;
        while(n>=10)
        {
            while(n!=0)
            {
                int r = n%10;
                sum = sum + (r*r);
                n = n / 10;
            }
            n=sum;
            sum=0;
        }
        if(n==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I submit the code , LeetCode says that for the input 7 the ouput  should be **TRUE**.
How is that even possible? Any number <10 is 100% not Happy , right ? 
PS : In Code::Blocks everything works fine.
Anyone else who encountered this ?

Comment: 7^2 = 49; 4^2 + 9^2 = 97; 9^2 + 7^2 = 130; 1^2 + 3^2 + 0^2 = 10; 1^2 + 0^2 = 1

Comment: So I guess you need to go through a complete squaring process even if the input number < 10. i.e. change your `while (n >= 10) { .. }` to `do { ... } while (n >= 10);`

Comment: Yes. See https://oeis.org/A007770

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a coding problem, but a misunderstood requirement.

Comment: 0 is unhappy trivially; 1 is happy trivially; numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 all end up in a cycle 4 ⟶ 16 ⟶ 37 ⟶ 58 ⟶ 89 ⟶ 145⟶> 42 ⟶ 20 ⟶ 4; they are unhappy.  As already noted, 7 maps to 1 (7 ⟶ 49 ⟶ 97 ⟶ 130 ⟶ 10 ⟶ 1) and hence is happy too.  It means you can diagnose happiness as soon as a number cycles to a single digit value, but both 1 and 7 lead to happiness and the remainder to unhappiness.

Answer (score 1):

> How is that even possible? Any number <10 is 100% not Happy , right ?

Wrong.  Trivially, 1 is less than 10 and is happy.  It turns out that 7 is also happy.  I haven't checked the other single-digit numbers.

The trick here is to detect when a number *isn't* happy.  What happens then?  Not much different, actually.  You can continue to compute the sum of the squares of the digits *ad infinitum*.  If that happens to result in 1 at some point, then all subsequent iterations will also produce 1, and then every number in the sequence, including the first, is a "happy number".  But if not, then there are only two possibilities:

- the sequence keeps increasing without bound, or
- the sequence cycles without passing through 1

It is a bit tricky to prove that for arbitrary inputs you do not get unbounded increase, but it is true.  That leaves you with the second option: a cycle.  The problem, then, is not so much to detect when the digit sum reaches 1.  That's the special case.  The actual problem is to detect cycles.

(Note: it's possible that such sequences starting from unhappy numbers have some property that would simplify detection, such as all passing through some specific number other than 1, but I am not aware of one.  That would not make the above comments incorrect in any case, but it might provide for a simple solution.)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution:

What's a happy number? Example :

```
Input: 19
Output: Yes
```

Explanation:

```
1^2 + 9^2 = 82
8^2 + 2^2 = 68
6^2 + 8^2 = 100
1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1
```

Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

```
function fun(n) {
  let count = 0;
  let res = "No"
  while (count <= 1000) {
    let digits = n.toString().split('');
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      a = +digits[i]
      sum += (a * a);
      n = sum
    }
    count++;
    if (sum == 1) {
      res = "Yes";
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(res)
}
```